# How to drop X-Forwarded-* headers in nginx ingress controller?

Tags: nginx-ingress

We are currently using nginx ingress controller as a reverse proxy between our application and the internet, and the application uses the `X-Forwarded-Host` header to perform redirects, which is required for its functioning.

Because of this, when the client adds the same `X-Forwarded-Host` header as part of their request, the page is wrongly redirected to the given value. To add complexity, the nginx ingress controller also populates the X-Forwarded-* headers as seen in its *nginx.tmpl* file, which causes values to stack.

Is there a way to completely drop all `X-Forwarded-*` headers when passing the request to the upstream application? Since all the requests coming to the controller are from the NLB, I'm assuming it shouldn't be used.

I tried setting `use-forwarded-headers: "false"` as shown in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-forwarded-headers) but is does not make a difference.